# Can anyone help me in proving this?

Tags: logarithms

As we know $e^{\ln (x)}=x$.

To prove this I applied $\ln$ on LHS (left hand side) and I got RHS (rights hand side ) as follows

$\ln (e^{\ln (x)})=\ln (x)$
 $\ln (x)\ln (e)=\ln (x)$
 $\ln (x)=\ln (x)$

But I didn't knew how the first step or the equation which is to be proved.
Can anyone help me in this.

Comment: By definition, $\ln$ is the inverse function of the exponential function, i.e. $\ln(e^x)=x$ and $e^{\ln(x)}=x$ for each $x\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/498598/prove-e-lnx-x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition,$$\ln e^{f(x)} = f(x)$$

Comment: Is it applicable for all types of function ?

Comment: @MurtuzaVadharia, yes, since it is true in each point.