# Proof of an identity with e and ln?

Tags: calculus

So my instructor just wrote up that $x^{\epsilon} = (e^{\ln x})^{\epsilon}$

Hmmm...... That's true, I'm sure, but I couldn't prove it. Can anyone show me the necessary manipulations?

Comment: $e^x$ and $\ln x$ are inverses of each other.

Comment: Yes, I know both of those. But I still can't quite see how they are applied here.

Comment: $e^{\ln x}=x$, by the definition of $\ln$.

Comment: if $x>0$ then $x=e^{\ln(x)}$ since $\exp$ and $\ln$ are inverse functions. SO just plug this in directly

Comment: Forget about the $\epsilon$. Already the terms without $\epsilon$ are equal, i.e., $x=e^{\log(x)}$. Then taking it to the power of $\epsilon$ gives your result. There is nothing more to prove.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove $e^{\ln{x}} = x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/498598/prove-e-lnx-x)

Comment: Ah, thanks for clearing that up. Yes I see it now. Thanks to Dietrich Burde for lifting the scales from my eyes. I also appreciate the others' quick replies. Much obliged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically we think of functions being inverses as a path towards simplifying an expression. That is, if I see $e^{\ln(x)}$ in the wild I can just as soon replace it with $x$, because, as we all know $e^{\ln(x)} = x$. However, this equality is just as true in reverse, $x = e^{\ln(x)}$. I can take the simpler $x$ and replace it with the more complicated $e^{\ln(x)}$ to, hopefully, (ab)use some properties of $e$ or of $\ln$ to solve whatever problem is at hand. Your professor has done exactly this.

Answer (score 1):

You should know that $\ln(x)$ is the inverse function of $e^x$. That means that $\ln(e^x)=x$ and that $e^{\ln x}=x, x>0.$

Rewriting your expression: We have $(x)^\varepsilon=\left(e^{\ln x}\right)^{\varepsilon}$.